# Cryptic Friends and Family: News of the Day

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

This puzzle is a cryptic family reunion, but we've again invited some close friends that are not actually family. The answer to this puzzle is a theme and a list of fourteen words or proper names or phrases; ten of them are related to the theme, the other four are close, but not actually on theme. Each of these is clued cryptically. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues uses family members (e.g., mom, sisters), or non-family members (e.g. friend) as appropriate, to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in alphabetical order, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Sister's exceptional charisma is lacking after dropping facade (7)
2. Auntie makes key choice of daycare options after school (6)
3. Friend's castle takes white's central pawn last (6)
4. Brother's cunning captures defended king and rook (7)
5. Acquaintance found gas nucleus ejected alpha particle (5)
6. Nephew, flooring accelerator into a corner, flips (5)
7. Copilot holding elevation (3)
8. Heat wave in CA city gets to Granddad (4)
9. Dad hauls down jib, stows it astern (5)
10. Alaska declines after setting record for children (6)
11. Son attains summit after steep scramble (6)
12. Mom's left soup in the refrigerator (9)
13. Concealing network hides note for daughter (5)
14. Azul mostly dropping odd colleague (5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they are all

> Current or former currencies of countries in the EU.
>  Most have been replaced by the Euro (family), the others are currencies of EU members which are not using the Euro (friends).

Answers

> 1. DRACHMA = (CHARISMA)* - IS + D
>  2. ESCUDO = ESC + U + D(aycare) + O(ptions)
>  3. FORINT = FORT taking (wh)I(te) and (paw)N
>  4. GUILDER = GUILE captured D(efended)  + R
>  5. KRONA = KR(ypt)ON + A
>  6. KROON = NOOK< with R from accelerator inside
>  7. LEV = (e)LEV(ation)
>  8. LIRA = LA holding IR
>  9. LITAS = SAIL< with T in
>  10. MARKKA = MARK + AK<
>  11. PESETA = (STEEP)* + A(ttains)
>  12. SCHILLING = S(oup) + CHILLING
>  13. TOLAR = TOR with LA inside
>  14. ZLOTY = (a)Z(u)L (m)O(s)T(l)Y

Not in the family

> I think FORINT, KRONA, LEV and ZLOTY are the currencies which have not been replaced by the Euro.

Title, as explained by El-Guest

> News of the day could mean **current** events (i.e, "currents"-y)

Comment: Well done - pretty much what I had too (had to put my daughter to bed and then got back to find you'd posted! Was missing #2...). rot13(Zl orfg org sbe 5 jnf CBHAQ (ercynprq ol gur Rheb va Plcehf) - SBHAQ -Syhbevar + 'nycun' (svefg bs) C(negvpyr))

Comment: @Stiv but I think they are alphabetical

Comment: You know, I hadn't even noticed that! Well done for nailing down the wordplay on that last one in the end +1

Comment: Dominated! Awesome job, hexomino!

Comment: News of the day, ie. rot13(_pheerag_ riragf)?

Comment: @El-Guest Ah, good point

Comment: Oh, a typo in your answer I think...#9 should be rot13(yvgnf), not rot13(yngvf).